# Keep the selected color by clicking even after reload the page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In my Date Picker, you can select date and time. I am using Javascript. You can select date and time by clicking. After selecting date, you will land up to time page. After selecting a time from timeslots, date and time both will go to server. I want to highlight the selected date and time with red color, even after reload the page color should be there. Date must be highlighted with time as well. So, that if you come back then date color should be highlighted too. Main thing, I want to store the color somewhere, so if I reload the page then I should see the color. Here, is my date and time getting JS code and I have added plunker below.

```js
datepicker = angular.module('datepicker', []);

datepicker.controller('dateTimePicker', ['$scope', '$http', 'formatDateTime', '$filter', function($scope, $http, formatDateTime, $filter) {
    
    $scope.showType = 1;
    $scope.selected = {};
    
    $scope.changeShowType = function (type) {
  $scope.showType = type;
  $scope.monthName = $filter('date')($scope.selected.date, 'MMM yyyy');
};
    
    $scope.selectDate = function(date) {
      console.log(date);
        $scope.showType = 2;
        $scope.selected.date = date;
        $scope.monthName = $filter('date')(date, 'dd MMM yyyy');
    };
    
    $scope.selectTime = function(time) {
        $scope.selected.time = time;
        $http.post('date/selected', $scope.selected);
    };

    var getTimeValues = function() {
        formatDateTime.getTimeValues();
    }
    getTimeValues();

    var bindScope = function() {
        $scope.timeValues = formatDateTime.timeValues;
    }

    bindScope();

    //Date Picker START

    var date = new Date();
    var months = [],
        monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var tempMonth;
    tempMonth = date.getMonth();
    for (var i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        months.push(monthNames[tempMonth] + ' ' + date.getFullYear());
        tempMonth += 1;
        if (tempMonth >= 12) {
          tempMonth = 0;
          date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1);
        }
    }
    $scope.year = 2015;
    $scope.changeMonth = function(steps) {
        if ($scope.monthIndex + steps >= 0 && $scope.monthIndex + steps <= 12) {
            $scope.dateValues = [];
            $scope.monthIndex = $scope.monthIndex + steps;
            $scope.monthName = $scope.months[$scope.monthIndex];
            var date = new Date();
            console.log(date.getMonth());
            var offset = date.getMonth()
            console.log($scope.monthIndex);
            var offsetDate = offset + $scope.monthIndex;
            $scope.nDays = new Date($scope.year, offsetDate + 1, 0).getDate();
            console.log(offsetDate + 1);
            console.log(new Date($scope.year, offsetDate, 1));
            for (i = 1; i <= $scope.nDays; i++) {
                var d = new Date();
                d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                var displayDate = new Date($scope.year, offsetDate, i);
                if (displayDate >= d) $scope.dateValues.push(displayDate);
            }

        } else {
            console.log("missed")
        }
        
        $scope.showType =1;
    };

    $scope.monthIndex = 0;
    $scope.months = months;
    $scope.monthName = months[0];
    $scope.changeMonth(0);


}]);

datepicker.factory('formatDateTime', [function() {
    return {
        //final structures which are bound to view
        //
        dateValues: [],
        timeValues: [],

        //generates one hour slots between minTime and maxTime
        getTimeValues: function() {
            console.log('here i am');
            var timeValues = this.timeValues;
            var minTime = 11; //vary this to change the first service slot available
            var maxTime = 19; //vary this to chage the last service slot available
            var string;
            for (var i = minTime; i < maxTime; i++) {
                if (i < 12) {
                    lowersuffix = 'AM';
                    startRange = i;
                } else if (i === 12) {
                    lowersuffix = 'PM';
                    startRange = i;
                } else {
                    lowersuffix = 'PM';
                    startRange = i - 12;
                }
                if ((i + 1) < 12) {
                    uppersuffix = 'AM';
                    endRange = (i + 1);
                } else if ((i + 1) === 12) {
                    uppersuffix = 'PM';
                    endRange = (i + 1);
                } else {
                    uppersuffix = 'PM';
                    endRange = (i + 1) - 12;
                }
                string = startRange + lowersuffix + '-' + endRange + uppersuffix;
                console.log(string);
                timeValues.push(string);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Plunker Link :- http://plnkr.co/edit/35UwiYLEqv3LYY6RiL1q?p=preview

Comment: [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) might help you with preserving data across pages :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use cookies to store the values

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe";
```

[W3Schools Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: I have tried those things, Not working. Can you please update the Plunker?

Answer (score 0):

If your target browser supports localStorage I would recommend:

```
localStorage.setItem("colour", "blue");
localStorage.getItem("colour");
```

Comment: I have tried, Not working. Can you please update the Plunker?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/GMM3nutbG1tnHx5pbgWt?p=preview I added set and get local storage variable in the setDate function. After refreshing the page "I am a test String!" shows in the console. If I understand correctly, persistance of the variable was your problem?

Comment: I am a test String! is not coming after refreshing the page, But whenever I am clicking on Date.

Comment: yeah, I put the console.debug inside the setDate function. The point being that you can see an old saved value even when you refreshed the page

Comment: Yeah, but I am not seeing any old saved value. Please correct me. If possible then show with any color which is easy to see.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/GUke3Y56RgA0KEiHmd2k?p=preview

First, you have no background color. Select a date and the console will print "setting color to green". Reload the page and the background is green.

Comment: Thanks. I got the concept.