# Change html language with a button and save after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how to save the html language on a website after reloading the page. I created a couple of language buttons, here's one example:

```
<a onclick="changeLang('pt')" href="#" title="Portugese" data-lang="Portugese">
   <div class="flag pt">Portugese</div>
</a>
```

And a bit of code in my JS file:

```
const changeLang = (languageCode) => {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute("lang", languageCode);
};
```

How can I make sure the language stays Portugese after clicking the button?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to store the language code in a cookie? Maybe in the `sessionStorage`

Comment: [Write a cookie with the language code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) when you set it, and then read in the code from the cookie when you reload the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep the selected color by clicking even after reload the page using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499363/keep-the-selected-color-by-clicking-even-after-reload-the-page-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few option, in my opinion best approach is to have different url for different language (domain.com, domain.com/pt, domain.com/fr) which is good for SEO.
You can also save language in cookie with javascript and then on page load fetch current language from cookie, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript) how to set and fetch cookie.